# Turn multiple key presses into single GameAction

Tags: c#, xna

The `InputHandler` class for my game detects key presses, turns each one into a `GameAction`, and raises an event:

```
public class InputHandler
{
    public delegate void ActionListener(GameActions gameAction);

    public event ActionListener ActionRequested;

    private void ProcessKeyboard(KeyboardState keyboardState)
    {
        var pressedKeys = keyboardState.PressedKeys();

        foreach (var inputAction in pressedKeys.Select(GetInputAction))
        {
            ActionRequested(inputAction.Down);
        }

        var releasedKeys = keyboardState.ReleasedKeys(prevPressedKeys);

        foreach (var inputAction in releasedKeys.Select(GetInputAction))
        {
            ActionRequested(inputAction.Up);
        }

        prevPressedKeys = pressedKeys;
    }
}
```

Only one `GameAction` can be requested at a time. This means that if you press the key bound to `GameActions.MoveUp` and the key bound to `GameActions.MoveLeft` at the same time, two separate events are raised and it looks like your character is moving diagonally.

Now, I need to detect this as a single `GameAction`, e.g. `GameActions.MoveUpLeft`. There has to be a better way to do it than what I've come up with.

```
private void ProcessKeyboard(KeyboardState keyboardState)
{
    var pressedKeys = keyboardState.PressedKeys();

    var inputActions = pressedKeys.Select(GetInputAction).ToList();
    var downActions = inputActions.Select(ia => ia.Down);

    if (downActions.Contains(GameActions.MoveUp) && downActions.Contains(GameActions.MoveLeft))
    {
        ActionRequested(GameActions.MoveUpLeft);
    }
    else if (downActions.Contains(GameActions.MoveUp) && downActions.Contains(GameActions.MoveRight))
    {
        ActionRequested(GameActions.MoveUpRight);
    }
    else if ...
}
```

I'm sure you can see how this can get quickly out of hand. How can I make it better?

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> var pressedKeys = keyboardState.PressedKeys();
> var inputActions = pressedKeys.Select(GetInputAction).ToList();
> var downActions = inputActions.Select(ia => ia.Down);
> ```

This is what's painted you into the corner you're in. You're not showing your `GameActions` enum (a better name would be `GameAction`, or even better, `MoveDirection`..actually, `Direction` suffices, since all there is to it is a bunch of values that each represent a direction - the point is, enum type names should not be plural), but I presume it looks something like this:

```
public enum GameActions
{
    MoveLeft,
    MoveUpLeft,
    MoveUp,
    MoveUpRight,
    MoveRight,
    MoveDownRight,
    MoveDown,
    MoveDownLeft
}
```

The problem is that `MoveUpLeft` is a combination of `MoveUp` and `MoveLeft`, and since the enum type itself doesn't account for it, your code has to.

I'd suggest using a `[Flags]` attribute:

```
[Flags]
public enum Direction
{
    Left = 1,
    Top = 2,
    Right = 4,
    Down = 8
}
```

Then, instead of `downActions` being an `IEnumerable<GameActions>` and using LINQ `IEnumearble<T>.Contains` extension, you can add the values of all "down actions", and pass `ActionRequested` an enum value that represents the sum of all pressed directions, be it `Left+Top`, `Down+Right` or whatever. The [Flags] attribute merely serves as a visual cue to remind you that these values can be combined and, using [bitwise AND operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c) or simply, the `.HasFlag()` method, the handler can determine whether the received value 3 contains `Direction.Left`:

```
void ActionRequested(Direction direction)
{
    if (direction.HasFlag(Direction.Left))
    {
        // direction contains Direction.Left
    }
    if (direction.HasFlag(Direction.Right))
    {
        // direction contains Direction.Right
    }
    if (direction.HasFlag(Direction.Top))
    {
        // direction contains Direction.Top
    }
    if (direction.HasFlag(Direction.Bottom))
    {
        // direction contains Direction.Bottom
    }
}
```

---

It's not clear from your post exactly what `GetInputAction` does and what `downActions` means, so it's hard to recommend a change that will fit into your code, but here's some inspiration:

```
class Program
{
    [Flags]
    public enum Direction
    {
        Left = 1,
        Top = 2,
        Right = 4,
        Bottom = 8
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var direction = (Direction)3;
        Console.WriteLine("Direction: {0}", direction);
        Console.WriteLine("Left: {0}", direction.HasFlag(Direction.Left);
        Console.WriteLine("Top: {0}", direction.HasFlag(Direction.Top);
        Console.WriteLine("Right: {0}", direction.HasFlag(Direction.Right);
        Console.WriteLine("Bottom: {0}", direction.HasFlag(Direction.Bottom);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The flags thing is just what I was looking for. I knew there was some way to combine enum values but I couldn't even think of how to phrase what exactly I was trying to do.